# Hola, como puedo obtener el user ID del usuario que accede a las funciones trigger de firebase?

Tags: firebase, function

```
export const followingOnCreate = functions.runWith({ memory: '256MB', timeoutSeconds: 540 }).firestore.document('follow/{currentUid}/followings/{otherUid}').onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {
   // que usuario esta disparando esta funcion? como obtener el id? 
});
```

GRACIAS!!!

Comment: [Mira aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796385/5587982). Tendrías que buscarlo mediante: `context.params.id;` Si muestras en la consola el contexto podrás ver todo lo que se puede obtener de él:  `console.log(context);`

Comment: Si, gracias, pero me refiero al usuario que esta autenticado el UID, o currentUser... !!

Comment: Justamente todo ese está en el contexto, [lee la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)